# Clang linker problem for a 'Hello, World!' example

Tags: c, linker, clang

I just tried out the latest [LLVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LLVM) and [Clang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clang) trunk versions. They compiled without a single warning out of the box, but I'm having trouble linking a [Hello, World!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22Hello,_World!%22_program) example. My code is

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  printf("Hello, World!\n");
}
```

If I compile using

```
clang test.c
```

I get the following error

```
/usr/bin/ld: crt1.o: No such file: No such file or directory
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Using *-v* shows that the GNU [ld](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_%28computing%29#GNU_linker) is invoked as:

```
"/usr/bin/ld" --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_i386 -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux.so.2 -o a.out crt1.o crti.o crtbegin.o -L -L/../../.. /tmp/cc-0XJTsG.o -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lc -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed crtend.o crtn.o
```

But I have the crt1.o object file!

```
locate crt1.o
```

Output:

```
/usr/lib/Mcrt1.o
/usr/lib/Scrt1.o
/usr/lib/crt1.o
/usr/lib/gcrt1.o
```

This also works:

```
clang -c test.c
gcc test.o
```

And of course

```
gcc test.c
```

What I further tried:

```
clang -Xlinker "-L /usr/lib" test.c

/usr/bin/ld: crt1.o: No such file: No such file or directory
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

clang -Xlinker "-L /usr/lib" test.c -v

"/usr/bin/ld" --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_i386 -dynamic-linker /lib/ld-linux.so.2 -o a.out crt1.o crti.o crtbegin.o -L -L/../../.. -L /usr/lib /tmp/cc-YsI9ES.o -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lc -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed crtend.o
```

I also tried copying the *crt1.o* file into the current directory. That seemed to work. Well, it didn't compile because after that *crti.o* was missing.

My Linux distribution is [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29).

Well, I don't really know what to try next. I don't see how I could fix clang nor do I have an idea on how to inject the necessary path in the *ld* invocation. Any ideas?

Comment: I only have a brief description of -Xlinker in my clang's page but isn't -Xlinker supposed to be passed twice for options with an arguments? This is what gcc's man pages says for -Xlinker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be the Clang version which can't detect the host's Linux version and GCC version...

This code in Clang which must add path to the crt*:

`llvm → tools → clang → lib → Driver → Tools.cpp`

```
  CmdArgs.push_back(Args.MakeArgString(getToolChain().GetFilePath(C, "crt1.o")));
  CmdArgs.push_back(Args.MakeArgString(getToolChain().GetFilePath(C, "crti.o")));
  CmdArgs.push_back(Args.MakeArgString(getToolChain().GetFilePath(C, "crtbegin.o")));
```

and the GetFilePath will try to search asked files in `getFilePaths()` list of current ToolChain (file `clang/lib/Driver/ToolChains.cpp`). If it can't find a file it will return the Name unchanged.

Comment: Curiously the implemtation of that function I have differs from the one you quoted... However adding Paths.push_back("/usr/lib");Paths.push_back("/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4/"); did the trick. If I interprete the code I have correctly then it only looks in /usr/lib when /usr/lib64 does not exist. However that directory exists on my system

Comment: there was a very old quote. now I get the http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/lib/Driver/ and can check code for your combination of clang rev, ubuntu  and gcc version

Comment: Code of `GetFilePath()` trys to open a file asked (crt1.o) in every directory in `getFilePaths()` list. It will stop if there is a file somewhere or it will return file name without the path

Comment: I've had good success setting the environment variable COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.4 with the latest clang out of SVN (version 3.1SVN).

Comment: sam, what is the exact svn revision and branch?

Answer (score 1):

This horrible *hack* "fixes" compiling/linking with Clang 3.0 (r142716) on [Ubuntu 11.10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_11.10_.28Oneiric_Ocelot.29) x86 (Oneiric Ocelot).

In the file included from */usr/include/stdio.h:28*:

> /usr/include/features.h:323:10: fatal error: 'bits/predefs.h' file not found
>
> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find crt1.o: No such file or directory 
> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory

```
diff --git a/lib/Driver/Driver.cpp b/lib/Driver/Driver.cpp
index 75300b5..3e2be30 100644
--- a/lib/Driver/Driver.cpp
+++ b/lib/Driver/Driver.cpp
@@ -241,6 +241,7 @@ Compilation *Driver::BuildCompilation(ArrayRef<const char *> ArgList) {
   // FIXME: Handle environment options which affect driver behavior, somewhere
   // (client?). GCC_EXEC_PREFIX, LIBRARY_PATH, LPATH, CC_PRINT_OPTIONS.

+  PrefixDirs.push_back("/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu");
   if (char *env = ::getenv("COMPILER_PATH")) {
     StringRef CompilerPath = env;
     while (!CompilerPath.empty()) {
diff --git a/lib/Frontend/InitHeaderSearch.cpp b/lib/Frontend/InitHeaderSearch.cpp
index b066e71..c6ffee8 100644
--- a/lib/Frontend/InitHeaderSearch.cpp
+++ b/lib/Frontend/InitHeaderSearch.cpp
@@ -562,10 +562,12 @@ void InitHeaderSearch::AddDefaultCIncludePaths(const llvm::Triple &triple,
       AddPath("/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu", System, false, false, false);
       AddPath("/usr/include/i686-linux-gnu/64", System, false, false, false);
       AddPath("/usr/include/i486-linux-gnu/64", System, false, false, false);
+      AddPath("/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/64", System, false, false, false);
     } else if (triple.getArch() == llvm::Triple::x86) {
       AddPath("/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/32", System, false, false, false);
       AddPath("/usr/include/i686-linux-gnu", System, false, false, false);
       AddPath("/usr/include/i486-linux-gnu", System, false, false, false);
+      AddPath("/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu", System, false, false, false);
     } else if (triple.getArch() == llvm::Triple::arm) {
       AddPath("/usr/include/arm-linux-gnueabi", System, false, false, false);
     }
```

Comment: This patch is not necessary anymore since r143344, r143345, r143346.
The problem should be fixed now.
see http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=11223

Answer (score 1):

On the most recent (3.5) release this sort of problem has cropped up again for anyone who does a build using the `--with-gcc-toolchain` configure option on a system with a pre-GCC 4.7 libstdc++ library installed.

You'll see it in two flavors:

```
echo '#include <string>' | clang++ -xc++ -
<stdin>:1:10: fatal error: 'string' file not found
#include <string>
          ^
1 error generated.
```

... as well as not being about to find the various crt files.

In both cases, the following allows you to work around the problem until it gets fixed:

```
printf '#include <string>\nint main(int argc, char *argv[]) { return 0; }' > /tmp/blah.cc

# Fixes issue not finding C++ headers; note that it must be gcc >= 4.7
clang++ --gcc-toolchain=/path/to/gcc/install -c -o /tmp/blah.o /tmp/blah.cc

# Fixes the link error
clang++ --gcc-toolchain=/path/to/gcc/install /tmp/blah.o /tmp/blah
```

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
clang -v
```

In my example, the output is:

```
clang version 3.0 (tags/RELEASE_30/final)
Target: armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabi
Thread model: posix
```

Run the following as *root* to use the target to create the missing directory as a link:

```
ln -s /lib/arm-linux-gnueabi /lib/armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabi
ln -s /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi /usr/lib/armv7l-unknown-linux-gnueabi
ldconfig
```